# How to add separators to static quicklists in Unity?

Tags: unity, launcher, quicklists

I created a firefox quicklist as shown below,

[image]

However I would like to also add commonly used websites in that quicklists under a separate group. To present it visually nice I would like to add separators (white lines as seen in the screenshot) to separate that from the other existing commands.

Is there any code or any other way to do this?

**How do I add a separator to the quicklists in unity?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put your own separator with em-dash characters buts its not an "Official" separator as per Jorge Castro's answer,and, will have a slightly different look.  Insert a shortcut group for the separator. For example:

```
[sep Shortcut Group]
Name=———————————
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Note that I named my separator group "sep" so you need to place "sep" (wthout quotes) into the "Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=..."

Example:

```
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Home;Desktop;Documents;Music;Pictures;sep;Win
```

This will place a separator below my Pictures shortcut and above my Win shortcut.
With gedit, the emdash is achieved by pressing Ctrl-Shift+U2014 (Use keypad & ensure num-lock is ON).  It is then easier to clipboard copy this character & then pasting it (using Ctrl-V) multiple times. (9 or 10 of these is good enough).

Also, you may notice that the "sep" shortcut group has no need for an `Exec=` line as there is no need to execute anything.